# Parsing specific category websites with generalized parser

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, nutch, fuzzy-logic

I want to parse several eCommerce websites product pages using Apache Nutch. Currently I am using domain/website specific parser by defining the CSS selectors for  Jsoup using different XML file for every site. Now I have to cover a large number of eCommerce websites and defining separate XML files for each websites is not a good idea.

I want to develop a generalized parser to parse the specific contents from a large set of eCommerce websites. As the structure of all the eCommerce sites are pretty close, I am planning to define some generalize extraction rules to cover all the sites. I read about [Bolierpipe](https://github.com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe) but I think that is specialized for article extraction.

How can I achieve this? Will I need to develop some machine learning algorithm or fuzzy logic or anything else? I have very limited knowledge of machine learning or fuzzy logic but I am interested to learn if I get the precise direction about what I will need to do for this problem?

Can you please give me some possible directions/approach to achieve this? Thanks!